# html/jquery: target iframe form request?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a module that submits a form request which unfortunately needs to be pulled in as a iframe.. The problem is that the result loads inside the frame when I want it to take over the same page.

form target="_top" and target="_parent" don't work..

is there a way I can achieve this through jQuery, since its loaded anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Targeting "_top" should work.  What browser are you using, and how are you submitting the form?  Also, do you control the page in which the iframe is loaded?  If not, might there be client-side script in that page that is interfering with your form submission?

Comment: submitting through POST.  Yes there is a ridiculous amount of partner JS so it could be many things.  I'm thinking I can force a window.top on the receiving page somehow? (I can control this as well).